# How to use soundex function in Ebean

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean, fuzzy-search

Is there any DB-agnostic way to call `soundex` or similar function for fuzzy searches using ebean (or any other ORM API)?

Comment: Take a look at jOOQ - I dropped Ebean in favour of it, and it works beautifully.  For your specific question, see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2969

Answer (score 0):

There is a soundex() DB function in Postges, MySql, Oracle, H2, SQL Server so that makes it a good candidate for DB agnostic support.

With Ebean ORM you could use it right now via:

```
String soundexArg = "Jones";

List<Customer> customers = ebeanServer.find(Customer.class)
.where().raw("soundex(lastName) = soundex(?)",soundexArg)
.findList();

// Note that lastName is detected as a property name and 
// translated into db alias and column as expected
```

You could also use raw() with Ebean's type safe "query beans" but it would be nicer in that case to add soundex as a fully supported expression on String property types that can be used like:

```
String soundexArg = "Jones";

List<Customer> customers = new QCustomer()
 .lastName.soundex(soundexArg)
 .findList();
```

This assumes that translates to SQL predicate: soundex(lastName) = soundex(?).